# Navigate file easily in Linux GUI Apps?

Tags: files, filesystems

This is not about File Manager as I can copy/paste or type the full path in the address bar. This question is about other apps, e.g. FeatherPad text editor.

If you have a file buried deep within your hard drive, navigating its full path can take forever. You have to click directory one by one in order to get to the file location.

In Microsoft Windows, you can navigate easily by typing the full path on the address bar. Unfortunately, this is not possible in Linux.

As example, I've been trying to open a file via FeatherPad text editor. As you can see in the address bar, it's not possible to type the path in address bar or copy/paste.

[image]

This is screenshot from Window's notepad. As you can see, it is possible to type full path or copy/paste in it's address bar.

[image]

Would it be possible to do that? If yes, please let me know how.

If not, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and enter the editors name followed by the path to the file. Example:

```
featherpad /path/to/file
```

You can copy paste to the terminal by selecting a text and then middle mouse button click in the terminal or in some terminals you can paste the clipboard content using ctrl-shift-v or shift-insert.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the application (or, more accurately, on the GUI framework in uses). For two popular ones:

#### GTK file dialog

There is a pencil icon to open a field where you can enter a file name (or a path, to go to that directory):

[image]

#### Qt file dialog

(at least as used in KDE apps). The dialog can be used in "Navigate" mode or in "Edit" mode. In the latter, you can paste a file specification. In that mode you can also navigate quickly using tab completion:

[image]